# On selecting or on entering data, the value should be updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the data get updated or appended , like in the case of the first element using prompt. In the first case when i click ok in prompt it gets updated, but in the 2nd it still remains in the date input tag and doesnt get updated. Same goes for dropdown , after i choose i should get the value updated

```
<div class="tabbable">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <table id='table-draggable1'>
            <tbody class="connectedSortable">
                <tr>
                    <th>col1</th>
                    <th>col3</th>
                    <th>col4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">256</td>
                    <td class="date">25-4-1992</td>
                    <td class="masterlist">0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    $(".desc").dblclick(function ()
{
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    var inputNewText = prompt("Enter new content for:", OriginalContent);
    if (inputNewText != null)
    {
        $(this).text(inputNewText);
    }
});

$(".date").dblclick(function ()
{
    var inputNewText = '<input class="date" type="date"/>';
    if (inputNewText != null)
    {
        $(this).html(inputNewText);

    }

});

$(".masterlist").dblclick(function ()
{
    var OriginalContent = $(this).html();
    var inputNewText = '<select class="masterlist"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
    if (inputNewText != null)
    {
        $(this).html(inputNewText);
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XyV5/

Comment: Do you want something like this on second td http://jsfiddle.net/5XyV5/1/

Comment: yes similarly for the dropdown as well.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie already provide an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically changing the elements the events are connected too, so need to use *delegated event handlers*. Replacing the element, even with the same class/id, does not reconnect your event handler to the new DOM element:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5XyV5/2/

```
$(document).on("dblclick",".desc", function ()
    {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        var inputNewText = prompt("Enter new content for:", OriginalContent);
        if (inputNewText != null)
        {
            $(this).text(inputNewText);
        }
    });



$(document).on("dblclick", ".date", function () {
    var inputNewText = '<input class="date" type="date"/>';
    if (inputNewText != null) {
        $(this).html(inputNewText);

    }

});

$(document).on("dblclick",".masterlist", function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).html();
    var inputNewText = '<select class="masterlist"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
    if (inputNewText != null) {
        $(this).html(inputNewText);
    }

});
```

They work by listening for the named event, bubbled up to a non-changing ancestor element (document in this example), *then* they apply the jQuery filter, *then* they call the function only on matching elements *that caused the event*.

You normally attach them to the nearest non-changing ancestor for efficiency (so probably `".connectedSortable"` in your case, but `document` is the default fallback (do not ever use `'body'` for delegated events as `body` has problems with some events due to styling considerations).

e.g.

```
$(".connectedSortable").on("dblclick",".desc", function ()
```

Comment: Hi thanks , i will definetly follow it. And can u help me with updating field oso. like the desc field. So that my page will look very neat. I tried to figure it out but wasnt able too

Comment: You should ask about the styling on a separate question, but what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Please check the first column. Afte i give the value on the prompt the value is updated in the html

Comment: @Cerebus1504: I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain in more detail what you are after?

Comment: If u check the jsfiddle.net/5XyV5/1 . . Here as soon as the first 2 fields are edited it gets updated. but the dropdown does not . . Please Check that. If u still dint understand let me know